# probleme in my html code to add website link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm preparing a phone application.I want to add a website link to a button.It works when I am using my pc.when I try my application on the phone device ,the button don't work.This is my code:

```
<li>
<a href="http://www.enit.rnu.tn" class="button scrolly"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> My site Web</a>
</li>
```

Comment: uh.  Code?  I see none.  Ah. There we go...  (edited)

Comment: If I drop that into a fiddle, it works fine.  At least in that, it creates a hyperlink for the text.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided. The issue must lie elsewhere.

Comment: when i try it on my phone using the software phonegap it doesn't work

Comment: well currently we don't have enough input to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your question, but does the console say something? I assume you are using Phonegap/Cordova? You should have installed the inappbrowser plugin. Your config.xml should contain something like:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

This allows every domain to open. In your case this:

```
<access origin="*enit.rnu.*" />
```

should do the trick.